# Adverbs: "tight" vs "tightly"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, licensing

> **Tight** is used as an adverb following verbs that denote a process of closure or constriction, as *squeeze, shut, close, tie*, and
> *hold*, denoting the state resulting from the process, whereas tightly denotes the manner of its application.
>
> *The windows were frozen tight* rather than *tightly*, since in this case the tightness of the seal is not likely to be the result of the
> manner in which they were *frozen*.
>
> *Tight* can be used only following the verb: *The house was shut **tight*** or ...*tightly shut*.

--[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tight)

The same dictionary distinguishes two senses for the adverb *THIN*, but the second one is in my opinion an adjective with the verb cut used copularly meaning "become"

> 1. In a thin manner: *Spread the varnish **thin** if you don't want it to wrinkle*. [Seed sown **thin**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thin#Adverb)
> 2. So as to be thin: *Cut the cheese **thin***.

OED: [TIGHT](https://oed.com/oed2/00252669) vs [TIGHTLY](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00252684)

Why isn't *tight* an adjective as is *dead* in *shoot someone dead*?

Secondly, I don't fully grasp the distinction between tight(ly), especially regarding the example of the windows.

Finally, why can't [shut be an adjective](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/shut) in the last example?

Comment: If I wish to keep a secret, I will keep my mouth tight shut.

Comment: GJC, in those examples the adjective - *tight* - is used as a Predicative Complement. They are not adverb in neither *"the house was shut tight"* nor in *"the window was frozen tight"* nor in *"Spread the vernish thin"* nor in *"Cut the cheese thin"*.

Comment: Certain verbs license adjectives rather than adverbs to complete the meaning. There are a myriad of such cases in English. By the way, it is great to see oldi @Man_From_India commenting here :)

Comment: A good first question, but please limit yourself to just one question per post. If you want to know about "thin" vs "thinly", please ask that in a separate question post.

Comment: In "*Paint the house white*", "white" is an adjective and not an adverb of manner. "Thin" seems the same to me. I checked Merriam-Webster and they agree. I'd like to know the dictionaries' basis for the claim that they're adverbs.

Answer (score -1):

Adjectives answer or enable the question "which?" or "what?"

Adverbs answer or enable the question "how?"

Sometimes the concern of "how" is the actual execution of a verb (tightly turn the car around the curve--qualify process of turning), and sometimes it's the desired end state (shut the door tight--desired end state is a door that has no space/ability to move).

> Spread the varnish thin

How did you spread the varnish?  You spread it in a way such that the end state is thin varnish.

> I ate the thin cookies.

> but the second one is in my opinion an adjective with the verb cut used copularly meaning "become"

Which cookies did you eat?  The ones that are thin.

---

> but the second one is in my opinion an adjective with the verb cut used copularly meaning "become"

Copular verbs don't communicate the meaning of modifying physical state--the most they do is rename or identify.

Given *X looks Y* as an example - there is no meaning that Y's state will be modified.

If *X cuts Y*, Y is definitely going to be physically altered - and that's not a meaning copular verbs cover.